# Using JSON and HTTP Request in C#

Tags: c#, android, sql-server, json, xamarin

I'm currently developing an Android app and I'm using [Connect Android to MS SQL Server Tutorial](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/connect-android-to-ms-sql-server-tutorial.13166/) to link my MSSQL server to the code.

And the first part is good though the second part is using a third party program to code which I don't want to. I want to write the whole code in C# (I'm using [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/)).

I found out [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) / [Json.NET for Xamarin](http://components.xamarin.com/view/json.net) website.

Though how am I supposed to use the HTTPUtils and requests in C# ? An example would be great.

Also, I have kind of a newbie question, I'm trying to get to the root of the code I sent, the .aspx file, and I don't quite understand where the web method is, I am used to a seperate .asmx file containing [Web Method]s that define them and then I can use them freely by creating a web reference on an .aspx file, so, where is the web method in the code I sent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static String getJsonData(String webServiceName,String parameter)
{  
try  
{
    String urlFinal=SERVICE_URI+"/"+webServiceName+"?parameter=";
    HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(urlFinal.trim()+""+URLEncoder.encode(parameter,"UTF-8"));

    postMethod.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    postMethod.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpResponse response = hc.execute(postMethod);
    Log.i("response", ""+response.toString());
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

    string=responseText;
    Log.i("Output", ""+responseText);
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

return string;
}
```